# How to disable debug messages on sockjs- STOMP

Tags: javascript, websocket, socks, stomp

I have the follow situation:

```
 var options = {
        protocols_whitelist : [ "websocket", "xhr-streaming", "xdr-streaming", "xhr-polling", "xdr-polling", "iframe-htmlfile", "iframe-eventsource", "iframe-xhr-polling" ],
        debug : false
    };

    var socket = new SockJS("/mmyurl/",undefined,options);
    var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({
        company : "XXXXX"
    }, function(frame) {
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/mytopic', function(message){ 
            var myitem = JSON.parse(message.body);

        });
```

all works fine, the problem is that on the javascript console is full of debug messages like this:

```
<<< MESSAGE
content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
subscription:sub-1
message-id:o6g660dt-113
destination:/topic/mytopic
content-length:411
```

And I want to disable the messages.

I tried to change some option and also tried to register simply:

```
var socket = new SockJS("/mmyurl/");
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to disable the debug messages?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Ok I found a solution.

I added this code:

```
stompClient.debug = null
```

In this way, the debug function is disabled.

Comment: For anyone else coming here, the documentation (http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/) states that you can set client.debug to any function, and that function gets run with each message. So in addition to being able to set debug to `null` you can change it to any function to manage your own debugging (set it by a GET variable or anything you want)

Comment: It should be set to a function doing nothing. The current StompJS version does not check if debug is set, it will just try to execute it. When setting debug to null, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 54):

I tried JR's answer but started receiving errors - changing debug to an empty function worked ...

```
stompClient.debug = () => {};
```

Comment: or `stompClient.debug = f => f;` (I find this easier to type)

Comment: This is now the best answer in 2022

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter Stomp.js logs you can use the following impl.

```
stompClient.debug = (log) => {
   if (JSON.stringify(log).includes('SUBSCRIBE')) {
      return;
   }
   window.console.log(log);
};
```

Comment: This just print logs sometimes, and nothing some others. And never return anything. How does printing things on the console (and doing nothing else) solve the problem? (But for the fact that this is, besides log printing, a function doing nothing, and, apparently, a function doing nothing is a working answer... if we believe the  decade old answer that already says that). Please, when answering old questions, be sure that you bring something new that wasn't already said in existing answers.