# How to disable logging to sockjs-client

Tags: javascript, sockjs

I initialize sockjs-client like this:

```
    sock = new SockJS(url,null,{transports:['xhr-polling']});
```

I want to disable console logging which I see in console:

```
sockjs.min.js:27 XHR finished loading: POST "https://...
sockjs.min.js:27 XHR finished loading: POST "https://...
```

How can I do this? 
PS: this question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683022/how-to-disable-debug-messages-on-sockjs-stomp), because I don't use STOMP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable debug messages on sockjs- STOMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683022/how-to-disable-debug-messages-on-sockjs-stomp)

Comment: @PatrickHund, I don't use STOMP.